# How can I remove element from an array from mongodb database and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Writing this query in [ROBO 3T](https://robomongo.org/) the code is running properly But in nodejs the code is not working.
//schema model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    image: [{
        type: String
    }],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

const Image = module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

//this code run properly

```
db.images.updateOne(
{_id:ObjectId("5eeb3273977faa1f7419620e")},
{ $pull: { image: "image-1592472179452.png"} }
)

    //this code not run

Image.updateOne({ _id: "5eeb3273977faa1f7419620e" },{$pull:{image: "image-1592472179482.png"}});
```

Comment: any error codes?

Comment: I'm not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Change your export:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```